# In KQL how can I use bag_unpack to turn a serialized dictionary object in customDimensions into columns?

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm trying to write a KQL query that will, among other things, display the contents of a serialized dictionary called Tags which has been added to the Application Insights `traces` table `customDimensions` column by application logging.

An example of the serialized Tags dictionary is:

```
{
    "Source": "SAP",
    "Destination": "TC",
    "SAPDeliveryNo": "0012345678",
    "PalletID": "(00)312340123456789012(02)21234987654(05)123456(06)1234567890"
}
```

I'd like to use `evaluate bag_unpack(...)` to evaluate the JSON and turn the keys into columns. We're likely to add more keys to the dictionary as the project develops and it would be handy not to have to explicitly list every column name in the query.

However, I'm already using `project` to reduce the number of other columns I display.  How can I use both a `project` statement, to only display some of the other columns, and `evaluate bag_unpack(...)` to automatically unpack the Tags dictionary into columns?

Or is that not possible?

This is what I have so far, which doesn't work:

```
traces 
| where datetime_part("dayOfYear", timestamp) == datetime_part("dayOfYear", now()) 
    and message has "SendPalletData"
| extend TagsRaw = parse_json(customDimensions.["Tags"])
| evaluate bag_unpack(TagsRaw)
| project timestamp, message, ActionName = customDimensions.["ActionName"], TagsRaw
| order by timestamp desc
```

When it runs it displays only the columns listed in the `project` statement (including TagsRaw, so I know the Tags exist in `customDimensions`).

`evaluate bag_unpack(TagsRaw)` doesn't automatically add extra columns to the result set unpacked from the Tags in `customDimensions`.

**EDIT:** To clarify what I want to achieve, these are the columns I want to output:

| timestamp | message | ActionName | TagsRaw | Source | Destination | SAPDeliveryNo | PalletID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**EDIT 2:** It turned out a major part of my problem was that double quotes within the Tags data are being escaped.  While the Tags as viewed in the Azure portal looked like normal JSON, and copied out as normal JSON, when I copied out the whole of a customDimensions record the Tags looked like `"Tags": "{\"Source\":\"SAP\",\"Destination\":\"TC\", ...` with the double quotes escaped with backslashes.

The accepted answer from David Markovitz handles this situation in the line:

```
TagsRaw     = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions["Tags"]))
```

Comment: TRAP FOR YOUNG PLAYERS: If double quotes are escaped with backslashes in the log data the Azure portal hides the backslashes (at least in JSON data added to `customDimensions`), so they look like normal double quotes.  However, KQL seems to parse escaped and unescaped double quotes differently (at least when they're in JSON data).  So hiding the backslashes makes it very difficult to figure out why a query doesn't work.  You can copy the JSON data and it won't have the backslashes so when you embed it into a sample query it will work fine.  But the same query won't work against the real logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

- When filtering on timestamp, better use the timestamp column As Is, and do the manipulations on the other side of the equation.
- When using the `has[...]` operators, prefer the case-sensitive one (if feasable)
- Everything extracted from dynamic value is also dynamic, and when given a dynamic value [parse_json() (or its equivalent, todynamic())](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction), simply returns it, As Is.
  Therefore, we need to treet `customDimensions.["Tags"]` in 2 steps:
  1st, convert it to string. 2nd, convert the result to dynamic.
- To reference a field within a dynamic type you can use `X.Y`, `X["Y"]`, or `"X['Y']`.
  No need to combine them as you did with `customDimensions.["Tags"]`.
- As the [bag_unpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin) plugin doc states:

  > "The specified input column (Column) is removed."

  In other words, `TagsRaw` does not exist following the `bag_unpack` operation.
- Please note that you can add prefix to the columns generated by `bag_unpack`. Might make it easier to differentiate them from the rest of the columns.
- While you can use `project`, using `project-away` is sometimes easier.

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let traces = 
print    c1 = "some columns"
        ,c2 = "we"
        ,c3 = "don't need"
        ,timestamp          =   ago(now()%1d * rand())
        ,message            =   "abc SendPalletData xyz"
        ,customDimensions   =   dynamic
                                (
                                    {
                                        "Tags":"{\"Source\":\"SAP\",\"Destination\":\"TC\",\"SAPDeliveryNo\":\"0012345678\",\"PalletID\":\"(00)312340123456789012(02)21234987654(05)123456(06)1234567890\"}"
                                       ,"ActionName":"Action1"
                                    }
                                )
;
// Solution starts here
traces 
| where         timestamp >= startofday(now())
            and message has_cs "SendPalletData"
| extend        TagsRaw     = todynamic(tostring(customDimensions["Tags"]))
               ,ActionName  = customDimensions.["ActionName"]
| project-away  c*               
| evaluate      bag_unpack(TagsRaw, "TR_")
| order by      timestamp desc
```

| timestamp | message | ActionName | TR_Destination | TR_PalletID | TR_SAPDeliveryNo | TR_Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-27T04:15:07.9337681Z | abc SendPalletData xyz | Action1 | TC | (00)312340123456789012(02)21234987654(05)123456(06)1234567890 | 0012345678 | SAP |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/SampleLogs?query=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)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've run the solution against our logs and I still don't see any columns from within the Tags.  No columns labelled "TR_", or with the names of the properties in Tags.  I removed the `project-away` to see what I was getting and I can see TagsRaw and ActionName columns, both populated.  I copied one of the TagsRaw records into Notepad++ and ran JSON Viewer > Format JSON and it worked, confirming the contents of TagsRaw are valid JSON.  I've also run your sample code verbatim and it works so not sure why I'm seeing a different result for the real data.

Comment: Also tried running your sample code but replacing your sample Tags data with a copy of a Tags record from our logs.  That works, so there is nothing wrong with the format of the Tags data in our logs.

Comment: Got to the bottom of it. Double quotes in the Tags were being escaped. While the Tags as viewed in the Azure portal looked like normal JSON, and copied out as normal JSON, when I copied the whole of the customDimensions the Tags looked like `"Tags": "{\"Source\":\"SAP\",\"Destination\":\"TC\", ...` with the double quotes escaped with backslashes.  I was able to get things working by getting rid of the backslashes: `TagsRaw = parse_json(replace_string(tostring(customDimensions["Tags"]), '\\', ''))`.  This does seem awfully complex, although it works.  Is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Comment: No need for that. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use project to limit the number of columns that are displayed, but you also want to include all of the unpacked columns from TagsRaw, without naming all of the tags explicitly.

The easiest way to achieve this is to switch the order of your steps, so that you first do the project (including the TagsRaw column) and then you unpack the tags. If desired, you can then use project-away to specifically remove the TagsRaw column after you've unpacked it.